# Complex If statements; || not working as I hoped

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I feel like this is a really dumb question but my brain is fried. Right now I'm working on a very complex set of if and else statements and I'm wondering if there is an easier way? I originally tried or statements but that didn't give me the desired result.

```
if(fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === '' && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === '' ) {
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
} else if(fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === city && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === '') {
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === '' && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === '') {
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === ''){
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === '' && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && fields[3].value === '') {
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === '' && fields[2].value === '' && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)) {
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === city && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && fields[3].value === ''){
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === '' && fields[2].value === '' && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)){
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && fields[3].value === ''){
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city && fields[2].value === '' && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)){
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if(fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)){
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: does this code do what you want it to do?

Comment: What is an `or` statement? Am I being trolled?

Comment: @AluanHaddad - I think OP means `||`

Comment: Please edit your question, change the title and describe the problem appropriately. Refer- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JaromandaX no, I think we are being trolled.

Comment: he said "I originally tried or statements but that didn't give me the desired result" - possibly trying to combine all those `if`'s into a single `if` with some `||` (or)

Comment: Whatever your condition , you call the same function :(

Comment: consider looking for `state machines` serach for it on google and you will get lot of resources, a small state machine can be used here to avoid this mess. you will be amazed and get a newer perspective to solve such things.

Comment: not whatever, only  those 11 sets of conditions

Comment: This does do what I want it just looks horrible and yes I mean || when i said or.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you use `OR Statement (||)` but you can use one `if statement`.

```
if(
    (fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === ''       && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === '') || 
    (fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === city     && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === '')  ||
    (fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === ''    && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === '') || 
    (fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city  && fields[2].value === '' && fields[3].value === '') || 
    (fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === ''   && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && fields[3].value === '') || 
    (fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === ''   && fields[2].value === '' && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)) || 
    (fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === city && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && fields[3].value === '') || 
    (fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === ''    && fields[2].value === '' && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)) || 
    (fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city  && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && fields[3].value === '') || 
    (fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city  && fields[2].value === '' && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)) || 
    (fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city  && (fields[2].value <= sq && sq != null) && (fields[3].value >= sq  && sq != null)) 
){
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
}
```

Comment: This might be a better way of writing it. I didn't think of using || like that.  Thank you! I was trying to get away without using so man different conditionals but I don't think I have a choice

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring it into something like this

```
if (sq != null) {
if (fields[3].value >= sq &&
    fields[2].value <= sq &&
    fields[0].value === state &&
    field[1].value === city) {

    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);

} else if (fields[3].value >= sq) {
    if ((fields[0].value === state) ||
        (fields[0].value === state && field[1].value === city) ||
        (fields[0].value === '' &&
            field[1].value === '')) {

        clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
    }
} else if (fields[2].value <= sq) {
    if ((fields[1].value === city) ||
        (fields[0].value === state && field[1].value === city) ||
        (fields[0].value === '' && field[1].value === '')) {

        clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
    }
}
} else if ((fields[1].value === '' && fields[0].value === state) ||
(fields[0].value === '' && fields[1].value === city) ||
(fields[0].value === state && fields[1].value === city)) {

clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
}
```